# Connect two people to same server?

Tags: javascript, php

Okay what Im asking is - Is it possible somehow that lets say one user clicks a button on the webpage and it changes the background color for another user / all other users?

Comment: Huh? Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: Have you looked at something like this? [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @Anders exactly what i meant, thank you for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

emm ... if you asking if it is posible , Yes it is .

You can use **socket.io** , it is a librery to send  and listen data in "real time" .
In you page  you can  listen if other user change the color and you can send it to change  , and in a few milisecons,  if your configurations and code are correct ,  you will be able to  change the color of the background  for all users

More information [here](https://socket.io/)